# Site for css styles?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I am trying to use more flexbox and css grids so I am not seeing the full use of stuff like materialize css and bootstrap. However I do like the designs of their stuff like(card panels from materialize) but I don't want really want to import all their stuff stuff(css, js) just for a few styles.

So I am wondering if there is just a style that has like the css code for making buttons, card panels and etc that I could just copy into my own css files.

I know I can just go with the inspector and grab the styles from bootstrap and materialize but alot of times styles are getting overwritten and multiple classes are being applied.

Comment: Do you want to learn and actually master your stuff, or just do copy & paste?

Comment: Inspecting is the way to go, yes. If you look at the _computed styles_, it doesn't really matter what classes cause this style or if they are overwritten or not.

Answer (score 0):

I see three options for you:

1. **Easy and obvious:** Include just CSS files, not JS, to achieve the same styles.
2. **Dirty and tedious:** Copy out styles manually into your code.
3. **Right and educating:** Utilise some CSS metalanguage like SCSS. Then if you get e.g. Bootstrap with package manager like `npm i -D bootstrap` you can import e.g. button styles with:

   ```
   @import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables';
   @import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/buttons';
   ```

   or materialize-css:

   ```
   @import 'node_modules/materialize-css/sass/components/variables';
   @import 'node_modules/materialize-css/sass/components/buttons';
   ```

Comment: I am using SCSS right now with npm. I did not know you could only import certain elements like that. Does that work with materializecss as well?

Comment: @chobo2 Any issues trying that yourself? :) I have updated the answer...

Comment: @smaji - I just got around to trying this. I am using their alpha 1.0 version of materialize and I did this in my js file import button from '../../node_modules/materialize-css/sass/components/_buttons.scss'; however I get    Undefined variable: "$button-border". There must be some dependency file I guess.? Also why do you use @import? vs import from? I get unexpected token when I try to build with webpack

Comment: @chobo2 Because obviously these are not imports in .js files, but in your own .scss/.sass files which is the right place to put them... ;)